# Having trouble returning through multiple classes in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm still learning and like to build things that I will eventually be doing on a regular basis in the future, to give me a better understanding on how x does this or y does that.

I haven't learned much about how classes work entirely yet, but I set up a call that will go through multiple classes.

```
getattr(monster, monster_class.str().lower())(1)
```

Which calls this:

```
class monster:
def vampire(x):
    monster_loot = {'Gold':75, 'Sword':50.3, 'Good Sword':40.5, 'Blood':100.0, 'Ore':.05}
    if x == 1:
        loot_table.all_loot(monster_loot)
```

Which in turn calls this...

```
class loot_table:
def all_loot(monster_loot):
    loot = ['Gold', 'Sword', 'Good Sword', 'Ore']
    loot_dropped = {}

    for i in monster_loot:
        if i in loot:
            loot_dropped[i] = monster_loot[i]

    drop_chance.chance(loot_dropped)
```

And then, finally, gets to the last class.

```
class drop_chance:
def chance(loot_list):

    loot_gained = []

    for i in loot_list:
        x = random.uniform(0.0,100.0)

        if loot_list[i] >= x:
            loot_gained.append(i)

    return loot_gained
```

And it all works, except it's not returning loot_gained. I'm assuming it's just being returned to the loot_table class and I have no idea how to bypass it all the way back down to the first line posted. Could I get some insight?

Answer (score 1):

Keep using `return`.

```
def foo():
  return bar()

def bar():
  return baz()

def baz():
  return 42

print foo()
```

Comment: Will I have to define loot_gained in each class definition it's using then?

Comment: Uh, no... you just need to keep using `return`.

Comment: I'm just beginning to confuse myself with all the coding I've done to that... sorry about that. I forgot to set getattr to print, and did as you suggested as well. But, I'm getting a return of the location of loot_table. "<__main__.loot_table object at 0x000000000340B3C8>"

Comment: Then you have another bug in your code unrelated to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I haven't learned much about how classes work entirely yet...

Rather informally, a class definition is a description of the object of that class (a.k.a. instance of the class) that is to be created in future. The class definition contains the code (definitions of the methods). The object (the class instance) basically contains the data. The method is a kind of function that can take arguments and that is capable to manipulate the object's data.

This way, classes should represent the behaviour of the real-world objects, the class instances simulate existence of the real-world objects. The methods represent actions that the object apply on themselves.

From that point of view, a class identifier should be a *noun* that describes category of objects of the class. A class instance identifier should also be a *noun* that names the object. A method identifier is usually a *verb* that describes the action.

In your case, at least the `class drop_chance:` is suspicious at least because of naming it this way.

If you want to print something reasonable about the object--say using the `print(monster)`--then define the `__str__()` method of the class -- see [the doc](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__).